# Can I select any Database Port in PostgreSQL? How does that choice affect me?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am really a beginner, however I learn fast and I thought that PostgreSQL was interesting, so I am studying it, but it does not look like this question has been asked. The default database port seems to be 5432, but what that number means? Can I put any number?

Sorry if this is out of place, really new to this world!

Comment: This Question is better asked on sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify any port you wish, subject to the limits of your host OS (Unix-oriented OSes restrict access to ports under 1024) and your sysadmins’ rules. Generally best to choose a port number not [already claimed by an app](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) that might be in use on your servers.

Postgres does not care about which port you choose. But you must communicate to Postgres if you want it to listen for incoming connections on any port other than the default 5432. Do so by changing its configuration settings.

The client app connecting to the Postgres server must also be configured to use the correct port if you are not using the default 5432.

If you build your own Postgres by compiling from source, you can specify a different default port as discussed [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/install-procedure.html).

If you install more than one Postgres cluster on a machine, as happens when testing multiple versions of Postgres, then you *must* change the port number. Each cluster must be listening on its own port number.

Comment: In addition to the answer above - one reason  you might wish to change from the default port is for security.  Pen testing usually recommend this as using the default port can be considered a security weakness.

Comment: @smbennett1974 That is what is called "security by obscurity" and is justly frowned upon, as it gives a false sense of security.